# How to copy file from current location to C:\ using cmd

Tags: command-line, script, batch-file

How to make script file that copies `MyFile.exe` from the current location  to `C:\`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following cmd line:

```
copy MyFile.exe C:\
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the question was "how to make script file".  So there should be an `echo > scriptfile.cmd` in front of that. ☺